# How to overwrite image if it already exists - Wordpress, Gravity form

Tags: functions, images, uploads, plugin-gravity-forms

How do I make the old file replaced when the user uploads a new one?

Now the files are named a1.jpg, a2.jpg, a3.jpg. If the user uploads a.jpg, then I want to overwrite the a.jpg that already exists. This shall only apply to this folder / form.

I use ultimate member together with gravity forms and gravity view. Have a form where the owner of the role (company) can upload their own company logo. It gets the renamed to the user role and is placed in a special folder.

So far I've managed to do this:

- Rename the file to the user's role - Done
- Put the file in a dedicated folder - Done
- **If the image already exists, overwrite it - Not done**

The full code can be found here:
https://github.com/gravitywiz/snippet-library/blob/master/gravity-forms/gw-gravity-forms-rename-uploaded-files.php

The configuration in functions

```
# Configuration

new GW_Rename_Uploaded_Files( array(
'form_id' => 10,
'field_id' => 6,
// most merge tags are supported, original file extension is preserved
'template' => '{Role:7}',
// Ignore extension when renaming files and keep them in sequence (e.g. a.jpg, a1.png, a2.pdf etc.)
'ignore_extension' => false,
) );
```

To put the files in the correct folder:

```
add_filter( 'gform_upload_path_10', 'change_upload_path', 10, 2 );
function change_upload_path( $path_info, $form_id ) {
    $path_info['path'] = '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads/company_logos/';
    $path_info['url'] = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/company_logos/';
    return $path_info;
}
```

So far everything is great. The only problem I have is that when the user uploads or changes the image, it should overwrite the old one. Now when the user uploads a new one, they are named **company.jpg, company1.jpg, company2.jpg** etc.

How do I make the old file replaced?

**UPDATE.** I found this code for another form. Can I use it in some way for my function?

```
<?php
add_filter(
    'wp_unique_filename',
    function( $file_name, $ext, $dir, $cb, $alt, $no ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST[ 'action' ] ) && 'forminator_submit_form_custom-forms' === $_POST[ 'action' ] ) {
            if ( $no ) {
                $find          = '-' . $no . $ext;
                $original_name = str_replace( $find, $ext, $file_name );
                return $original_name;
            } else {
                return $file_name;
            }
        }

        return $file_name;
    },
    10,
    6
);
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines of code and can help you to overwrite image

```
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id, true);

        if(isset($file) && !empty($file) ){

            $upload_overrides = array('test_form'=> false);
            $movefile = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);

            $filename = basename( $movefile['url'] );

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );

            $attachment = array(
                'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $filename,
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',

            );

            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $movefile['url'], $post_id );
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $movefile['url'] );
            // wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id), "single-post-thumbnail")[0];
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);

            
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very good at coding. I guess I have to edit this code somehow. Found this. If file exists Do Something?    `foreach ( $uploaded_files as $_file ) {`

`if ( in_array( $_file, $stashed_files ) ) {`
`$renamed_files[] = $_file;`
`continue;`
`}`

`$dir  = wp_upload_dir();`
`$dir  = $this->get_upload_dir( $form['id'] );`
`$file = str_replace( $dir['url'], $dir['path'], $_file );`

`if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {`
`continue;`
`}`